# Allowing bookings of o365 room for external users

Tags: office-365

I have a O365 tenant with a bunch of resources (=rooms) in it, e.g. `room1@foo.com`, and a few users, e.g. `user1@foo.com`.

The rooms are possible to book for users within the tenant, i.e., `user1` may schedule a meeting in `room1`, but I now want to make them available also for some external users, let's call it `test@bar.com`.

I've read a ton of guides such as [this](https://resolve.co.uk/blog/article/allow-external-users-to-book-in-office-365-resource-calendar) and [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/sharing-meeting-rooms-between-2-office365/c5d6ba4e-678a-49c1-8780-ca39fdb2c0d0) and [this](https://dotsh.no/2020/02/14/enable-external-booking-of-meeting-rooms/) about this, and they all pretty much say the same thing; it's the `ProcessExternalMeetingMessages` property that allows this. If it's enabled, by default *anyone* should be able to send a scheduling request to the resource's mailbox.

So from PowerShell I've done

```
> Set-CalendarProcessing -Identity Room1 -ProcessExternalMeetingMessages $true
```

I've verified that the change is in effect:

```
> Get-CalendarProcessing -Identity Room1 | fl ProcessExternalMeetingMessages

ProcessExternalMeetingMessages : True
```

I've also published the calendar:

```
Set-MailboxCalendarFolder Room1:\Calendar -PublishEnabled $true
```

This gives me a public URL in which the calendar is viewable with free/busy information.

Furthermore, I've added my user as a delegate to the resource so that I can view its mailbox, verified that "Everyone" is allowed to book the resource, verified that there are no custom transport rules preventing e-mail delivery to the resource, and even explicitly shared the calendar with my external user `test@bar.com`.

Still, when trying to book a meeting with the resource as the location, there's never any response. The event is not added to the room calendar, there is no accept/decline answer sent back to the booking user, and there is no invitation e-mail in the resource's mailbox. It's clear that external meeting requests are *not* processed.

If I book the room from `user1@foo.com`, it instantly responds with an accept, and in the resource's mailbox the received invitation and the sent response is visible.

I feel like I've turned every stone now, trying to understand why this room cannot be scheduled. Every guide says that if `ProcessExternalMeetingMessages` is `true`, by default *anyone* may schedule that resource, but I cannot even do it after explicitly publishing and sharing the calendar with my particular user.

How could I debug this further? Is there any global setting that could override the `ProcessExternalMeetingMessages` settings, such as a policy that blocks or restricts external messages on a higher level?

Answer (score -2):

Powershell commands in here will help you
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/rooms/with-office-365?tabs=m365-admin-center%2Cazure-active-directory2-password

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Fromm [answer]: **Provide context for links** 
Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the external resource is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Links to other websites should always be helpful, but avoid making it necessary to click on them as much as possible.